# How to get accurate and consistent coordinates from click event on canvas?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, canvas, ionic4

I’m creating a module that displays a body diagram and the EMS tech can click on different body parts to calculate total burn area on a victim.

I’m grabbing the coordinates on the javascript canvas based off the (click) function on the canvas and it works fine in the ionic lab.

Once I deploy to android, the coordinates seem to be off to a point where it’s unusable. Is there a way to get consistent coordinates?

I've tried moving things around and leaving the canvas at a static size, but the coordinates are still different.

html file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/burntools"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Adult Burn Calculator</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content no-bounce>
  <canvas #canvasEl width="{{this.canvasWd}}" height="400" (touchstart)="touchStart($event)" (touchend)="touchEnd($event)" (click)="clickIt($event)"></canvas>
</ion-content>
  <ion-footer class="fixedFooter">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons>
        <ion-button slot="start" (click)="switchSides('front')" color="{{this.frontColor}}">
          <ion-icon name="Body"></ion-icon>
          Front
        </ion-button>
        <span style="font-weight: 700;">Burn %: {{this.theScore}}</span>
        <ion-button (click)="switchSides('back')" color="{{this.backColor}}" slot="end">
          <ion-icon name="body"></ion-icon>
          Back
        </ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-footer>
```

ts from click handler

```
 clickIt(ev) {
    console.log('Click It');
    const canvasPosition = this.canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    console.log('x', ev.clientX - canvasPosition.x);
    console.log('y', ev.clientY - canvasPosition.y);

    const tempX = ev.clientX - canvasPosition.x;
    const tempY = ev.clientY - canvasPosition.y;
}
```

The results in the ionic lab are consistent and the app works as expected.  As soon as I deploy it to my android device, the coordinates are off significantly.

Comment: Hey John, you mention device (Android) that is using touch events but your code shared here is referring mouse events. Do you get wrong coordinates from your touchstart?

Comment: can you share your methods: touchStart($event) touchEnd($event)

Comment: The touchStart/touchEnd weren't even firing.